# switch statement not applying a button tag as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

in my program a switch statement is used to assign specific buttons specific properties, one of these properties is assigning a 'correct' tag for the button that the user needs to click to answer the question correctly. The problem I'm having is that for some reason the incorrect buttons are displayed a "you guessed correct" message when only the button with the 'correct' tag should be doing this.

```
        public void SetButtonContent(string chosenMetal, TextBlock reagentText, TextBlock transMetalText,
        Button opt1, Button opt2, Button opt3, Button opt4, Button opt5, Button opt6, Button opt7, Button opt8)
    {
        string pickedMetal = chosenMetal;
        string pickedReagent = CycleThroughReagents();

        reagentText.Text = pickedReagent;
        transMetalText.Text = pickedMetal;

        BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
        switch (pickedMetal)
        {
            case "Copper": //this is only one out of six cases, but all the cases have relatively the same format.
                opt1.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.hexAqColour, Cu.hexAqFormula, Cu.hexAqState);
                opt1.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt2.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.dilNaOHRctColour, Cu.dilNaOHRctFormula, Cu.dilNaOHRctState);
                opt2.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt3.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1}", Cu.excessNaOHColour, Cu.excessNaOHFormula, Cu.excessNahOHState);
                opt3.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt4.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.dilNH3RctColour, Cu.dilNH3RctFormula, Cu.dilNH3RctState);
                opt4.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt5.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.ExcessNH3Colour, Cu.ExcessNH3Formula, Cu.ExcessNH3State);
                opt5.Background = Brushes.DarkBlue;

                opt6.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.saltRctColour, Cu.saltRctFormula, Cu.saltRctState);

                opt7.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.Na2CO3RctColour, Cu.Na2CO3RctFormula, Cu.Na2CO3RctState);
                opt7.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                opt8.Content = string.Format("{0} \n {1} \n{2}", Cu.ClRctColour, Cu.ClRctFormula, Cu.ClRctState);
                opt8.Background = Brushes.Yellow;

                if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[0])
                    opt1.Tag = "correct";

                if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[1] || pickedReagent == reagentsList[3])
                    opt2.Tag = "correct";
                    opt4.Tag = "correct";

                if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[2] || pickedReagent == reagentsList[5])
                    opt3.Tag = "correct";
                    opt6.Tag = "correct";

                if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[4])
                    opt5.Tag = "correct";

                if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[6])
                    opt7.Tag = "correct";

                else
                    opt8.Tag = "correct";
                break;



            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

The above method is used to set the button content and then the method below is in my 'MainWindow' code to handle each button being clicked.

```
    public void CheckForCorrect(Button button)
    {
        if ((string)button.Tag == "correct" && amtLeft != 0)
        {
            amtLeft -= 1;
            MessageBox.Show("You guessed correct!");
            _GameControl.SetButtonContent(chosenMetal, ReagentAdded, transMetal, Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4, Opt5, Opt6, Opt7, Opt8);
            button.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        if ((string)button.Tag != "correct" && amtLeft != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Oops!");
        }

        if (amtLeft == 0)
        {
            SwitchMetals();
        }


    }
```

The button content is first set with in the 'MainWindow()' class and is the first instance when the 'SetButtonContent' is executed in the program.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chosenMetal = "Copper";
        _GameControl.SetButtonContent(chosenMetal,ReagentAdded, transMetal, Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4, Opt5, Opt6, Opt7, Opt8);

        Opt1.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt2.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt3.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt4.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt5.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt6.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt7.Click += HandleButtonClicks;
        Opt8.Click += HandleButtonClicks;  
    }
```

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated as I am unsure were I am going wrong for this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple lines of code inside an if statement, you need curly braces around them.

In your code above, opt4 and opt 6 will always be set as “correct” as they are outside the if statement.

Also, if all of the if cases are exclusive, you should either specify them fully or else use `else if`. The way your code is now, if the `pickedReagent` is anything except `reagentsList[6]`, then opt8 is always set to “correct”.

Code with those fixes:

```
if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[0])
{
    opt1.Tag = "correct";
}
else if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[1] || pickedReagent == reagentsList[3])
{
    opt2.Tag = "correct";
    opt4.Tag = "correct";
}
else if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[2] || pickedReagent == reagentsList[5])
{
    opt3.Tag = "correct";
    opt6.Tag = "correct";
}
else if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[4])
{
    opt5.Tag = "correct";
}
else if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[6])
{
    opt7.Tag = "correct";
}
else 
{
    opt8.Tag = "correct";
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh thank you! I can't believe I made such a basic error haha

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pickedReagent == reagentsList[1] || pickedReagent == reagentsList[3])
                    opt2.Tag = "correct";
                    opt4.Tag = "correct";
```

Is this statement intended to set both opt2.Tag and opt4.Tag if the statement is true?  The way its written opt4.Tag will always get correct and opt6.Tag will as well

Comment: Yes that's suppose to happen, due to both buttons having the same content